# Add multiple frames together (more than two)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How would I add multiple dataframes together.  I have like 10 dataframes to sum up.  I tried to use

```
df_add = df1.add(df2, df3 fill_value=0)
```

And it doesn't work.

This is the code to create the dfs

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)], columns=['a','b'])


   a  b
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  5  6

df2 = pd.DataFrame([(100,200),(300,400),(500,600)], columns= 
['a','b'])

df3 = pd.DataFrame([(100,200),(300,400),(500,600)], columns= 
['a','b'])
```

Now how would I be able to add these so that

```
     a      b
0   201    402
1   603     804
2   1005    1206
```

Comment: What's wrong with `df1+df2+df3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the simple

```
sum((df1,df2,df3))
```

works and gives:

```
      a     b
0   201   402
1   603   804
2  1005  1206
```

Comment: `df1 + df2 +df3` is so much better.  See @rafaelc timings.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an addendum,

```
df1 + df2 + df3
```

works just fine. If performance is important and index matching is not important, then consider vectorized `np.sum` and avoid pandas overhead

```
%timeit np.sum([df1.values,df2.values,df3.values],axis=0)
27.2 µs ± 3.06 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit df1+df2+df3
1.21 ms ± 23.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit sum((df1,df2,df3))
2.04 ms ± 208 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: I agree it is not wise to use python `sum` on dataframe objects, best to let the dataframes handle sums or use numpy.